# Python Pillow Text auto wrap

Tags: python

I try to figure out how to auto wrap a text from pillow to my image. Somebody knows what I could try?

Until yet I have the following code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw 

my_image = Image.open("Template.png")

title_font = ImageFont.truetype('Ragniart.ttf', 200)
title_text = "The Beauty of Nature"
image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
image_editable.text((15,15), title_text, (237, 230, 211), font=title_font)
my_image.save("result.png")
```

And the result is:

[image]

How you can see it doesn’t wrap it?